# Why has my Photoshop Colour pallette gone so colourful?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs5, palette

I was happily working in Photoshop CS5 when I suppose I pressed something.  I don't know what, but ever since my palette shows up as extremely colourful:

[image: Photoshop Color Picker]

No black, white, grey appear, but I can still use them.

How can I revert back to before?

What is this mode for?

Comment: I see white (well, nearly white) right there in the upper right corner. I suspect if you move the slider to the bottom, it will change and black will be at the bottom left (with various grays appearing in the middle along the way)

Comment: Perhaps, but the below answer is better as it allows me to judge exactly what I'm doing visually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the **Blue** (B) modifier activated. Switch it back to **Hue** (H) for the familiar default.

[image: Photoshop Color Picker]

The purpose of these is to allow you to modify the individual components and (H, S, B, R, G, B, L a, or b) and provide visualization for the range. With the blue modifier active, you can quickly adjust the amount of blue in the color (0-255) by dragging along the color slider (the rainbow gradient box in the screenshot above).